# why is tls.getLegacyCiphers() not in node.js v10.38?

Tags: node.js, ssl, rc4-cipher

Hi I am using the IBM SDK for Node.js 1.1.0.14 , which is based on joyent v0.10.38.

I can use tls.getLegacyCiphers("v0.10.38") or tls.getlegacyCiphers() in
the IBM version of node.js
but I cannot find the same API in the joyent v0.10.38?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is newly added into the IBM SDK for Node.js version only.
The IBM SDK Node.js version 1.1.0.14 has removed the RC4 from the default set of ciphers used for the TLS protocol, to address the Bar Mitzvah security vulnerability

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/nodesdk/javascript_current_news_technote.html

This will be available in the future version of the joyent Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

IBM SDK for Node.js V1.1.0.14 has an early version of the RC4 fix. We have contributed the fix to Node.js and are waiting for Node.js 0.10.39 to become available.